# SSH wont log into VPS using DNS

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, linux-networking, ssh-keys

I'm working on a Virtual Machine where I have Ubuntu Server, in that server I connect to my cloud server (ubuntu), via ssh , but when I tried to log in with this syntax:

```
ssh subdomain.example.com
```

It brings this error :

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

But If I use any of this syntax :

```
ssh my_user@subdomain.example.com
```

```
ssh my_user@cloud_IP
```

I login without a problem. So I was just wondering If the first syntax is wrong or I have something messed up within `sshd_config` file or my cloud server firewall service configuration. I've used `ssh -vvv subdomain.example.com`
to debug it and this is what It shows: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFAej.png)

Comment: If the answer below didn't help you, can you explain what happens when you try it? Your question shows different behaviour only when not specifying a user

Comment: Instead of showing screenshots of terminal output, please copy and paste the output into your question, so it becomes searchable.

Answer (score 3):

Your user name on the client machine is used as default for `ssh` connection to remote machines. You say it works when you do:

```
ssh user@subdomain.mydomain.com
```

but not when you do:

```
ssh subdomain.mydomain.com
```

Therefore we must assume that your user name locally is not `user`.

If that is the case you can either specify `user` every time or you can add an entry to your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file that says "my user name at `subdomain.mydomain.com` is `user`":

```
Host subdomain.mydomain.com
    User user
```

DNS does not come in to it because both of your examples are connecting to the same host. If this is not the case and you have made a copy/paste/redaction error, please update the question and consider not redacting the real host names involved as it makes it harder to help you.

Answer (score 0):

SSH command syntax

ssh your_username@host_ip_address_or_domain_points_to_the_server_ip_address

usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
[-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
[-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
[-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
[user@]hostname [command]

Since the SSH client reads from the known_hosts file when connecting to a different system, the current user will need to have the proper permissions on that file.

Without the proper permissions, you may see an error like this.

http://puu.sh/HeLeg/bd3b712d1e.png

If using keys to authenticate (instead of a password) you'll be locked out of the system entirely until you fix the permissions on your key files. Running these commands or recheck the permission of the below, it should remedy the problem.

$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh

$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config

$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub